# How to send seekbar progress from second activity to first one continuosly in android

Tags: android, seekbar

I tried many times to get seekbar progress from an activity to another, It's working but when it comes to getting the value continuously it doesn't work. It only gives the progress once. Can anyone help me.

Sorry for the bad english :-)

Thank you.

Comment: Please post some code about your implementation.. you can use memorycache or SharedPreferences to share info between different classes with different contexts

Comment: Yep I tried Shared Preferences And Finally its working

Comment: Nice, i just posted an answer so in case anyone needs it.  Please check it as valid answer if it is okay, greetings!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to store your data inside SharedPreferences and then retrieve info later from other activity within different context. [Here is the link to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

Have a nice day!